# GoogleSpreadSheetで管理している情報を自動でExcelへ転記したい

Tags: google-apps-script, excel, vba, google-spreadsheet, google-api

GoogleSpreadSheetで現在管理している情報をExcelへそのまま自動で転記することができる仕組みを教えていただきたく。

目的としましては、現在作成しているVBAマクロで利用する情報がSpreadSheetで管理されており、手作業による転記作業を削減したいため。

何か良い手段等ございますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

スプレッドシートは既にある更新されないスプレッドシートをエクセル形式に変換したいのでしょうか。それとも常時更新されている状況のスプレッドシートをエクセル形式に変換したいのでしょうか。

**前者の場合**、スプレッドシートを開いて

```
ファイル -> 形式指定してダウンロード -> Microsoft Excel
```

で変換、ダウンロードすることができます。

**後者の場合**、状況によって２通り考えることができるかと思います。

A. スプレッドシート自体を公開しても良い場合

```
１．スプレッドシートのファイル -> ウェブに公開 -> エクセルに取り込みたいシートを選択 -> ウェブページとして公開 -> URLをコピー

２．エクセルのWebクエリ -> アドレス欄へコピーしたURLをペースト -> 取り込み　（変更タイミングはプロパティで設定）
```

この場合、スプレッドシートが変更されるとエクセルのそれに伴って中身も変更されます。逆はできません。

B. スプレッドシートが公開できない場合

```
GASを使用して定期的にスプレッドシートをエクセル形式に変換してメールで送る、あるいは自分から定期的にダウンロードさせる。
```

GASを使用した変換の場合はスクリプトを作成する必要がありますので、ご希望の場合はお時間を頂く必要が御座います。

**追記 :**

下記はローカルPCから直接Google Drive上のスプレッドシートをエクセルに変換してダウンロードするためのものです。
事前にアクセストークンを取得してください。アクセストークンの取得はこちらが分かりやすいかと思います。http://qiita.com/shin1ogawa/items/49a076f62e5f17f18fe5

取得したアクセストークンを使用して下記のcurlコマンドでスプレッドシートをエクセルに変換してダウンロードすることができます。

```
curl -LG \
-d "mimeType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer アクセストークン" \
"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/ファイルID/export" \
-o "エクセルファイル名"
```

アクセストークをAuthorizationへ入力し、ファイルIDをURLへ入れてください。最後にファイル名を指定して実行してください。ファイルIDは、スプレッドシートを開いたときのURLから下記の部分で取得できます。

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/この部分がファイルIDです/edit
```

Comment: Tanaikeさんご解答ありがとうございます。
今回の件では後者となります。

スプレッドシートをウェブに公開することは難しい為、日時でExcelに変換してメールで送る等の処理が必要になること理解いたしました。
具体的な処理やスクリプトが見えてこないため、スクリプトの作成も依頼させていただきたく存じます。

Comment: @aki 編集中に返事をしてしまったようですみません。後ほど更新した際にダウンロードするためのコードを掲載致します。

Comment: @aki どのような言語をお使いか分かりかねましたのでcurlでご用意しました。ご確認ください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！使わせていただきます。解決しなければまた質問させていただきます。

Comment: GASよりも簡単に扱うことができると思いましたのでcurlを選択しました。動作確認も行っていますのでご安心ください。ところで、アクセストークンを取得する際のscopeはhttps://www.googleapis.com/auth/driveだけで問題なさそうです。